# Trouble when trying to sync server content into Core Data - Magical Record insertion process is extremely slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, magicalrecord

I am able to successfully synchronise my database into core data. I use [MagicalRecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) as my Core Data wrapping interface.

The problem I am facing is that the process of inserting all information is really slow. 
I understand that this question might be too specific. But I truly believe that there is something trivial in the Obj-C code that I am missing.

**This is the structure of the partial DB that I am trying to sync**

[image]

**First some background info.**

Every **place** has:

- **one(1)** referenced row in place_contact_info
- **one(1)** referenced row in place_adjustments
- **seven(7)** referenced rows in place_opening_hours
- **zero(0) or more** referenced rows in place_tag **and** place_category.

The **database (server side)** currently consists of ~1000 places.

My PHP script on the server side delivers the representation of this data in JSON format.

**It is delivered like** [this](http://pastebin.com/SaDvS66z):

Here comes my insertion into Core Data logic.

`data` here is the complete representation of the partial database described in the link above.

```
+ (void)updateDatabaseWithPlaces:(NSDictionary *)data
{   
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizePlaces:[data objectForKey:@"places"]];
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizeContactInfo:[data objectForKey:@"place_contact_info"]];
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizeOpeningHours:[data objectForKey:@"opening_hours"]];
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizeAdjustments:[data objectForKey:@"place_adjustments"]];
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizeCategories:[data objectForKey:@"place_category"]];
    [FFSynchronizationHandler synchronizeTags:[data objectForKey:@"place_tag"]];

    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:SYNCHRONIZATION_COMPLETE object:nil];

    }];
}


+ (void)synchronizePlaces:(NSDictionary*)places
{
    for(id placeParams in places)
    {
        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:@([[placeParams objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue])];

        // if the place is flagged as deleted, delete that entity
        if([[placeParams objectForKey:@"is_deleted"]integerValue] == 1){
            [place MR_deleteEntity];
            continue;
        } else if(!place){
            // if the place does not exists in the database already, create it.
            place = [Place MR_createEntity];
        }
        place.place_id = @([[placeParams objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]);
        place.name = [placeParams objectForKey:@"name"];
        place.longitude = @([[placeParams objectForKey:@"longitude"]floatValue]);
        place.latitude = @([[placeParams objectForKey:@"latitude"]floatValue]);
        place.main_category = @([[placeParams objectForKey:@"main_category"]integerValue]);
        place.info_text = [placeParams objectForKey:@"info_text"] == [NSNull null] ? nil :[placeParams objectForKey:@"info_text"];
    }
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}


+ (void)synchronizeContactInfo:(NSDictionary*)contactInfoParams
{
    for(id contactInfo in contactInfoParams)
    {
        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:@([[contactInfo objectForKey:@"place_id"] integerValue])];

        // if the place that the contact info belongs to
        // is somehow not here, just continue the loop
        if(place == nil)
            continue;
        PlaceContactInfos *place_contact_info = [PlaceContactInfos MR_createEntity];
        place_contact_info.website = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"website"] == [NSNull null] ? nil :[contactInfo objectForKey:@"website"];
        place_contact_info.telephone = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"telephone"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"telephone"];
        place_contact_info.email = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"email"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"email"];
        place_contact_info.address = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"address"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"address"];
        place_contact_info.city = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"city"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"city"];
        place_contact_info.zip_code = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"zip_code"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"zip_code"];
        place_contact_info.country = [contactInfo objectForKey:@"country"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [contactInfo objectForKey:@"country"];
        place.place_contact_info = place_contact_info;

    }
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}

+ (void)synchronizeOpeningHours:(NSDictionary*)openingHoursParams
{
    for(id openingHours in openingHoursParams)
    {
        NSNumber* openingHoursId = @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]);
        NSNumber* placeId = @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"place_id"]integerValue]);
        NSNumber* isDeleted = @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"is_deleted"] integerValue]);
        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:placeId];

        // if the place is flagged as deleted, delete that entity
        if(isDeleted.integerValue > 0){
            PlaceOpeningHours *oh = [PlaceOpeningHours MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place_id = %@ AND oh_id = %@",placeId, openingHoursId]];
            if(oh)
                [oh MR_deleteEntity];
        } else {
            PlaceOpeningHours *oh = [PlaceOpeningHours MR_createEntity];
            oh.day =  @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"day"]integerValue]);
            oh.open = [openingHours objectForKey:@"open"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [openingHours objectForKey:@"open"];
            oh.close = [openingHours objectForKey:@"close"] == [NSNull null] ? nil : [openingHours objectForKey:@"close"];
            oh.always_open = @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"always_open"]integerValue]);
            oh.is_closed = @([[openingHours objectForKey:@"is_closed"]integerValue]);
            oh.place_id = placeId;
            oh.place = place;
        }

    }
     [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}


+ (void)synchronizeAdjustments:(NSDictionary*)adjustmentsParams
{
    for(id adjustmentParams in adjustmentsParams)
    {
        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:@([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"place_id"] integerValue])];
        // if the place that the adjustments belongs to
        // is somehow not here, just continue the loop
        if(place == nil)
            continue;

        PlaceAdjustments *place_adjustments = [PlaceAdjustments MR_createEntity];
        place_adjustments.parking = @([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"parking"]integerValue]);
        place_adjustments.elevator = @([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"elevator"]integerValue]);
        place_adjustments.toilet = @([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"toilet"]integerValue]);
        place_adjustments.ramp = @([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"ramp"]integerValue]);
        place_adjustments.availability = @([[adjustmentParams objectForKey:@"availability"]integerValue]);
        [place setPlace_adjustments:place_adjustments];
    }
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}

+ (void)synchronizeCategories:(NSDictionary*)placeCategoryParams
{
    for(id categoryParams in placeCategoryParams)
    {
        NSNumber* categoryId = @([[categoryParams objectForKey:@"category_id"] integerValue]);
        NSNumber* placeId = @([[categoryParams objectForKey:@"place_id"]integerValue]);
        NSNumber* isDeleted = @([[categoryParams objectForKey:@"is_deleted"] integerValue]) ;
        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:placeId];
        if(isDeleted.integerValue > 0){
            PlaceCategories *cat = [PlaceCategories MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place_id = %@ AND category_id = %@",placeId, categoryId]];
            if(cat)
                [cat MR_deleteEntity];
            } else {
            PlaceCategories *cat = [PlaceCategories MR_createEntity];
            cat.category_id = categoryId;
            cat.place_id = placeId;
            cat.place = place;
        }

    }
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}

+ (void)synchronizeTags:(NSDictionary*)placeTagParams
{
    for(id placeTag in placeTagParams)
    {
        NSNumber* tagId = @([[placeTag objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]);
        NSNumber* placeId = @([[placeTag objectForKey:@"place_id"] integerValue]);
        NSNumber* isDeleted = @([[placeTag objectForKey:@"is_deleted"] integerValue]);

        Place *place = [Place MR_findFirstByAttribute:@"place_id" withValue:placeId];
        if(isDeleted.integerValue == 1){
            PlaceTags *tag = [PlaceTags MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"place_id = %@ AND tag_id = %@",placeId, tagId]];
            if(tag)
                [tag MR_deleteEntity];

        } else {
            PlaceTags *tag = [PlaceTags MR_createEntity];
            tag.tag = [placeTag objectForKey:@"tag"];
            tag.place_id = placeId;
            tag.place = place;
        }

    }
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfAndWait];
}
```

From the first line of code until the

```
 [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveOnlySelfWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:SYNCHRONIZATION_COMPLETE object:nil];

        }];
```

is called roughly one minute passes.

How can this be optimised? Inserting this into MySQL only takes a second.
Thanks for you attention.

**EDIT 1**

After some profiling i realise that its the synchronisation of opening hours and tags that takes significant time. [image]

It is the `MR_findFirstMatchingAttribute` that is being run every time that is the time thief. Do you have any suggestions on how to optimise that?

Comment: Can you post an Instruments trace of the Core Data fetches and saves? A time profile would be helpful as well.

Comment: Perhaps the first step is to look into the documentation for Core Data and perform batch inserts for most of that data https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing everything in the main/default context. This is essentially the main thread context. By calling saveOnlySelfAndWait, you are blocking the main thread. This is possibly contributing to some synchronization locks.I recommend creating an entirely new background context, and perform all your saves there.